# Update Spring Tool Suite to version 3.9.0 (without reinstall it from zero)

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I'm using Spring Tool Suite:

Version: 3.8.4.RELEASE

Build Id: 201703310825

Platform: Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3)

Today its Dashboard noticed me that the new version 3.9.0 is available.
I tried to use the options menu "Help -> Check for update" and "Help -> Installation Details -> Update button" but no updates are found.

What is the correct procedure to update it, without to reinstall it from zero?

In this page: "https://spring.io/tools/sts/all" there are the "Update Site Archives" and "Update Sites". How I can use them?

Can I extract the archive and overwrite all files?

Or can I use the update site into the menu option "Help -> Install new software" ? (in this case, I have to choose Eclipse 4.6 because it is the current installed version, or can I have to choose Eclipse 4.7 because it is the newer?)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The update to 3.9.0 is extremely fresh, maybe some network and cloud caches need to grab it. That might be the reason why the "Check for Updates" doesn't say anything yet on your side. It should, once the updates propagated through the cache levels that might be around.

To double check, you can take a look at the `Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Update Sites` and check if there is the STS update site listed and active (the one for 4.6). If it is, you can also try to press "Reload". That could help in case p2 uses some stale cached data (and not the network or the cloud somewhere).

In case you have an Eclipse 4.6-based STS, you should continue to use the STS update site for 4.6 AND NOT THE ONE for 4.7. Mixing Eclipse versions in the STS update sites can cause unintended side effects - and in some cases cause parts of your installation to not work properly anymore.

Comment: I've added an answer for you to my question (there are not available characters for long comment)

Comment: Now I see the updates, but something go wrong:
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.vmware.vfabric.ide.eclipse.tcserver.core,3.9.0.201707061818-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.vmware.vfabric.ide.eclipse.tcserver.livegraph,3.9.0.201707061818-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.vmware.vfabric.ide.eclipse.tcserver.reloading,3.9.0.201707061818-RELEASE........

Answer (score 0):

Martin, I've exported the list of active sites in "Available Update":

```
<bookmarks>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/buildship/updates/e46/releases/2.x" selected="true" name="Buildship"/>
   <site url="http://jasperstudio.sourceforge.net/updates/" selected="true" name="Jaspersoft Studio Update Site"/>
   <site url="https://dl.bintray.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-eclipse-site/" selected="true" name="MapStruct Eclipse repository"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon" selected="true" name="Neon"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201612211000" selected="true" name="Neon"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20160221192158/repository/" selected="true" name="Orbit-R20160221192158"/>
   <site url="http://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.6" selected="true" name="SpringSource Update Site for Eclipse 4.6"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.6/" selected="true" name="The Eclipse Project repository"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/" selected="true" name="Xtext All In One (Releases)"/>
</bookmarks>
```

I guess that there isn't the site for the STS update "http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.6/" ... maybe this is the problem.
The solution is to add this site in the list?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, in case you don't have that update site around, you should add it... :-)